# sharing multiples items with sharekit on facebook

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, sharekit

I know how to share an image lonely:

```
// Create a UIImage.
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ShareKit.jpg"];

// Wrap the UIImage within the SHKItem class
SHKItem *item = [SHKItem image:image title:@"This image was sent with ShareKit!"];

// Create a ShareKit ActionSheet and Assign the Sheet an SHKItem
SHKActionSheet *actionSheet = [SHKActionSheet actionSheetForItem:item];

// Display the ActionSheet in the current UIView
[actionSheet showInView:self.view];
```

and how to share a link lonely:

```
// Create an NSURL. This could come from anywhere in your app.
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://mobile.tutsplus.com"];

// Wrap the URL within the SHKItem Class
SHKItem *item = [SHKItem URL:url title:@"Mobiletuts!"];

// Create a ShareKit ActionSheet and Assign the Sheet an SHKItem
SHKActionSheet *actionSheet = [SHKActionSheet actionSheetForItem:item];

// Display the ActionSheet in the current UIView
[actionSheet showInView:self.view];
```

but I don't know how to share both link and image in the same time. Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this one of two ways.


**1. Through the URL property of SHKItem.**

```
@property (nonatomic, retain)   NSURL *URL;
```

Like so:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://mobile.tutsplus.com"];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ShareKit.jpg"];
SHKItem *item = [SHKItem image:image title:@"This image was sent with ShareKit!"];
[item setURL:url];
```

**2. Using the +[itemFromDictionary:] class method of SHKItem**

```
+ (SHKItem *)itemFromDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dictionary;
```

Like so:

```
NSString *urlString = @"http://mobile.tutsplus.com";
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ShareKit.jpg"];
NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:urlString, @"URL", image, @"image", @"This image was sent with ShareKit!", @"title", nil];
SHKItem *item = [SHKItem itemFromDictionary:dictionary];
```

... and then sharing your item as desired. In your case, you can display using the -[actionSheetForItem:] method.

Comment: hi.. interested how to add description as well? meaning to say text, url and image at the same time?

Comment: any idea on that? need some guidance?

Comment: @lakesh the example I've given shows text, URL and image being shared in one request. See how the dictionary uses 3 key-object pairs in it's instantiation.

Comment: when i use your second method, I get this error: -[NSURL length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xadb73c0 ? Not sure how to solve this...

Comment: @lakesh change the url to an NSString and it will work. The initialization from the SHKItem assumes you entered an NSString and not an NSURL.

Comment: Has this functionality been removed form share kit?